# Как использовать конструктор при загрузке Parent'a FXMLLoader'ом

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

Добрый день. Я вычитал, что конструктор Controller'ов вызывается раньше метода initialize(...). Но я не знаю как передать параметры в конструктор. Единственный способ, который я знаю, это такой:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(...);
TestController testController = new TestController(some paremetrs);
loader.setController(controller);
loader.load();
```

Но мне это не нравится по определённым причинам, может есть способ сделать это как-то более правильно и красиво?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, через конструктор никак передать нельзя.

Одно из возможных решений - это передать параметры через сеттер(ы) уже после загрузки и инициализации контролера:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(...);
loader.load();

TestController testController = loader.getController();
testController.set(some parameters);
```

Правда, это сильно зависит от Вашей логики контролера и может быть сетить вдогонку новые параметры будет неудобно.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию